# Access component state from redux action

Tags: reactjs, state, redux

I need to preserver state changes on various component `onChange` events. hence I save those in their states, as saving straight to redux causes to much re-rendering and harms user experience, even causes bugs some times. I now need to grab states of all these components once user clicks on certain button and push these state values into redux (this bit is straight forward), but how can I access all component states within an action that will update redux state? As I need to access them individually.

Comment: "as saving straight to redux causes to much re-rendering and harms user experience, even causes bugs some times". This seems like the real issue to fix, as this has definitely _not_ been my experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should check whole workflow of your app, because saving field to redux should not make a big overhead for re-rendering.

Also you should understand what Actions are (from official documentation of Redux):

> Actions are payloads of information that send data from your
>   application to your store. They are the only source of information for
>   the store. You send them to the store using store.dispatch().

So action should contains all needed data inside itself.

If you choose to fire one action for whole form, you can go with this approach (contact form is a good example, because you want to send it only when it is fully filled).

First of all when you are doing button click, you should call function of parent `component` (which contains all of needed fields and know how to gather needed date).
Function of parent component can store all of field values in it's own `state`, or gather `states` of child `components`.
Then you will be able to dispatch action with needed params from this function (usually action dispatcher passed from `container`)

On official website you can find a good explanation: [UsageWithReact](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)